# jQuery UI effect() method overwriting CSS

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery UI effect() to make a div slide up. During the animation, the div's font-size is set to 100%, but my original CSS is `font-size:40px`. By making the animation moving very slowly, I was able to find out that during the animation, the method adds a wrapping div over my div, and the wrapping div is like this:

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%; background-color: transparent; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 1150px; height: 64px; float: none; overflow: hidden;">
```

The `font-size:100%` style attribute overwrites my original CSS for the target div. Now of course I can add `!important` to my CSS so it won't be overwritten, but I'd like to know if there is any other way to do this more legitimately than roughly adding `!important` to CSS. Also, I'd like to know what is the reason for the `font-size:100%` being added to the wrapping div.

Comment: Your inner div's CSS should take precedence over the UI div. Are you applying your styles to that div, or to some ancestor?

Comment: I see. I'm using some immediate child selector to control the CSS of the inner div. Now that the wrapping div is added, the selector got obseleted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file

```
.ui-effects-wrapper{overflow-x: visible !important; width: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

the ui-effects-wrapper is a pain to try to override... i used the following with the element i was trying to set the width for:

```
<div class="menuContainer"> //this is what the .ui-effects-wrapper acts on
  <div class="menuItem"></div>
  <div class="menuItem"></div>
  <div class="menuItem"></div>
</div>
```

I could not overwrite the .ui-effects-wrapper, so here is what i did to work with it.

```
in css page:
.menuContainer  {  
   top: 160px;
   position: absolute; //important to have
   height: 385px;
   width: 400px;  
   overflow-x: hidden; //this made the width "appear" like it stayed at 400px as is set above.
}

.menuItem {
    width: inherit; //and now everything is 400px and the css doesn't show the    extra crazy that the .ui-effects-wrapper was giving it.
    height: 10%; // made each item 10% of the menuContainer's height. I adjusted to where it looked right based on my font selection, padding, etc
}
```